# How to get value of xml column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, xml, xml-parsing, sqlxml

How to get XML value of column  ?

```
 SELECT PaymentMethodDetail.value('(/paymentMethodDetail/EFTPaymentDetails/AccountType/text())[0]','varchar(30)') as AccounType,* FROM paymentTable

<PaymentMethodDetail>
  <EFTPaymentDetails paymentMethodCode="">
    <AccountName>RVQNX BASAD</AccountName>
    <AccountType>S</AccountType>
  </EFTPaymentDetails>
</PaymentMethodDetail>
```

It is returning null value instead of S

Comment: XML is case sensitive, and you need to use [1]

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE paymentTable (
    PaymentMethodDetail XML
);

INSERT INTO paymentTable (PaymentMethodDetail)
VALUES
('<PaymentMethodDetail>
  <EFTPaymentDetails paymentMethodCode="">
    <AccountName>RVQNX BASAD</AccountName>
    <AccountType>S</AccountType>
  </EFTPaymentDetails>
</PaymentMethodDetail>')

SELECT PaymentMethodDetail.value('(/PaymentMethodDetail/EFTPaymentDetails/AccountType/text())[1]', 'varchar(30)') as AccountType, * 
FROM paymentTable
```

change the index from [0] to [1] in your XPath expression

Comment: A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is not provided. How can I test your answer?